# Add a calculation/formula to a column in data frame in r

Tags: r, statistics

I want to apply the following formula to couple of columns in my data frame. It's throwing NANs on the column I have applied it to. Would somebody please point out where am I getting it wrong? Also, if there's a `inf' or NA in one of the rows, how should that be dealt with?

Formula:

```
(((x - min(col))*9)/(max(col) - min(col))) + 1
```

Here'a sample dataframe df:

```
A     B    C 
1.2  122  0.1
2.2  121  0.2
4.5  134  0.4
```

Here's my code:

```
formula_gen <-function(x) {
  (((x - min(x))*9)/(max(x) - min(x))) + 1
}

df$d <- sapply(df$A, formula_gen)
```

This is my output:

```
A          
NAN
NAN
NAN
```

Comment: The `sapply` sends one value of `df$A` at a time to the formula, so the `NaN` is coming from dividing by zero `max(x)-min(x)`

Comment: `df$d <- formula_gen(df$A)` ?

Comment: That worked. Thanks jogo.

Comment: If there's a `inf' value in one of the rows, how should that be dealt with?